# MATLAB urlread - How to POST data in JSON format?

Tags: arrays, json, matlab, post, urlread

As I know ,the urlread function can post to the URL. I did it with the string.

```
urlread(url, 'Post', {'userId', userid, 'Password', Password}
```

but There are some JSON value like that:

```
"country": ["US","JP"],
"student": false,
```

I tried this code but it failed.

```
urlread(url,'Post',{'userId', userid ,'Password' ,Password ,'country' ,'{'US' ,'JP'}' ,'student' ,false}
```

How can I POST data from Matlab to a RESTful server in JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

#### Matlab webwrite

You'll find that `urlread` has been replaced by [webread](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) and [webwrite](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html) and that it automatically handles JSON serialization. So you can just create a Matlab struct  and hand that to `webwrite`.

```
url = 'http://example.com'
data = struct('userId', userId ,'Password' , password, 'country', {'US', 'JP'}, 'student', false)
webwrite(url, data);
```